# Instructions in downvoted answer are unhelpful, encourages counter-productive behaviour

Tags: discussion, question-quality

Say I'm a user posting a question and get this error:

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details

And then I find [help in a Meta post about the same issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184921/stackoverflow-error-message-it-looks-like-your-post-is-mostly-code-please-add).

Being lazy I use the heavily downvoted suggestion which says to copy and include a paragraph from somewhere/something else that has no relation to the question at all. Which creates unnecessary noise.

Note: [this is not a hypothetical scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38394581/1).

Wouldn't it make sense to delete that unhelpful answer?

Comment: If you're stupid enough to use a grayed out answer with a big -18 in front of it, you deserve your question being closed. Even if you're new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Play stupid games, win stupid prizes.

Comment: See also: ["Yes, we should totally keep downvoted answers around, as 'warnings'!"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276201/automatically-delete-negatively-scored-answers-after-a-time/276236#comment895100_276236)

Answer (score 12):

> Say I am a bit lazy and use the heavily downvoted suggestion

Why would you go and use the advice in a downvoted suggestion? When it is greyed out and there is an answer with upvotes just above it? When the comments make it clear people think it is stupid advice?

That's not lazy. That's going beyond reason. And frankly, if someone goes ahead and does that, they deserve all the pain they get.

---

What you are suggesting could happen is not reasonable in my eyes. That it *may* have happened once or twice doesn't make it a big problem.

---

> **Wouldn't it make sense to delete that unhelpful answer?**

Sure. Vote to delete it then.

But - just deleting highly downvoted content automatically on the network meta doesn't make sense to me either, as the function of the site is also for discussions - some opinions may not be popular but they should still be seen and be around.

Point being - this needs to be done case-by-case.